HTML Popover Attribute Accessibility Issues for Date Input (Wonky Tabbing)
I'm busy taking a look at the HTML popover Attribute as a way to implement popovers without Javascript but it seems to have Accessibility Issues when the popovertarget contains a date input.
When trying to interact with the C: Not OK button and then tab through the date inputs, it doesn't work as expected and on Chrome it will skip the second date input completely.
I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if there is anything that can be done to get the date input tabbing working correctly (tab through each date field and the show calendar picker button)


<button popovertarget="popoverChild">Show me Wonky Tabbing</button>

<div id="popoverChild" popover>
  <p>Try to Tab through these Inputs</p>
  <div><input type="date" /></div>
  <div><input type="date" /></div>
</div>



JSFiddle

It seems to work fine for me (Chrome OS)

That's unexpected, I have the issue on Windows with Chrome, Edge and Firefox

I tested it on my laptop with Fedora Linux and Firefox, I had the issue

At least I know I'm not crazy now!

And my PC with Windows and Edge/Firefox Dev edition didn't work either

Could it be a browser bug?  I don't see another explanation for it?

Your code doesn't look wrong at first glance... Note that, in Chrome, the focus is in reality given to the iframe, never to any of the fields. I have also something bizarre, but different, with firefox: with Tab, all fields can get the focus but you can't go out of the fields once you are inside (is that wanted?), but you can reach the button with Shift+Tab only. Until it is fixed or clarified, maybe you can try using <detail>.

This isn't really much of an answer but after extensive testing with the HTML popover, it seems there are other issues across different browsers (aside from the unexpected tab functionality with date inputs). I encountered issues such as not closing on focus out and triggering window scrolls, I don't think it's ready for use in production just yet (even with polyfills)
